# PostgreSQL Streaming Replication

Tags: postgresql, replication

I'm trying to set up two PostgreSQL servers on one machine and perform a streaming replication. I have succeeded once, but when i've tried again following exactly the same steps it doesn't work.. Those are the steps:
I have $PGDATA = home/postgresql/9.1/data
and $STANDBY = home/postgresql/9.1/data2

1. Set up two nodes:

`initdb -D $PGDATA`

`initdb -D $STANDBY`

1. In the master node create a user for replication. I do that in pgAdmin (it does have superuser privileges)
2. In the master node in pg_hba.conf add the part that allows standby to connect:

`host   replication     repuser         127.0.0.1/0            md5`

1. In the master node in postgresql.conf set:

`max_wal_senders = 1`

`archive_mode = on`

`archive_command = 'cp %p ~/postgresql/backup/archivedir/%f'`

`wal_level = archive`

`wal_keep_segments = 32`

1. Start the master node and do the base backup:

`psql -d dellstore2 -c "SELECT pg_start_backup('backup for replication',    true)"`

`rsync -av ${PGDATA}/ $STANDBY --exclude postmaster.pid`

`psql -d dellstore2 -c "select pg_stop_backup()"`

pg_stop_backup says that everything is fine, all the WAL files were archived

1. In the standby (data2) node I create recovery.conf with:

`standby_mode = 'on'`

`primary_conninfo = 'host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 user=repuser password=haslo'`

`trigger_file = '/home/michau/postgresql/replication.trigger'`

`restore_command = 'cp /home/michau/postgresql/backup/archivedir/%f "%p"'`

1. Start the master node, then start the standby node - replication should start and standby should catch up with the master. That was exactly what happened the first time.
   Now when I start the standby I get: **"Address already in use"** error.
   Of course both standby and master have the same port specified in postgresql.conf (they have exactly the same postgresql.conf files). If I change the port in standby to let's say 5433 then I get:

`LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2012-06-12 19:48:01 CEST`

`LOG:  entering standby mode`

`cp: cannot stat /home/michau/postgresql/backup/archivedir/000000010000000000000007: No such file or directory`

`LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/7000070`

`LOG:  record with zero length at 0/7000070`

`cp: cannot stat /home/michau/postgresql/backup/archivedir/000000010000000000000007: No such file or directory`

`LOG:  streaming replication successfully connected to primary`

`LOG:  redo starts at 0/7000070`

And it just hangs here. Running ps -ef | grep postgresql yields:

`michau    2491  1898  0 19:46 pts/0    00:00:00 postgres -D /home/michau/postgresql/9.1/data`

`michau    2493  2491  0 19:46 ?        00:00:01 postgres: writer process`

`michau    2494  2491  0 19:46 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process`

`michau    2495  2491  0 19:46 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process`

`michau    2496  2491  0 19:46 ?        00:00:00 postgres: archiver process   last was 000000010000000000000008`

`michau    2497  2491  0 19:46 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process`

`michau    2571  2214  0 19:49 pts/1    00:00:00 postgres -D /home/michau/postgresql/9.1/data2`

`michau    2572  2571  0 19:49 ?        00:00:01 postgres: startup process   recovering 000000010000000000000009`

`michau    2575  2571  0 19:49 ?        00:00:01 postgres: writer process`

`michau    2578  2571  0 19:49 ?        00:00:02 postgres: wal receiver process   streaming 0/99782DC`

`michau    2579  2491  0 19:49 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal sender process repuser 127.0.0.1(42142) streaming 0/99782DC`

`michau    2586  2491  0 19:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: michau postgres ::1(49941) idle`

`michau    2587  2491  0 19:51 ?        00:00:01 postgres: michau dellstore2 ::1(49942) idle`

The recovering 0000000010000009 where changing for a while, but for half an hour it doesn't anymore.

I'm sure there is something I must have done the first time and not written down or something, but I am at a complete loss to say what it was. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you'll have more chances for an answer at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know something like this exists.

Answer (score 3):

I went through the steps you posted above and I get the exact errors as you posted but I was able to solve the issue.

I tried to merge your steps with the steps posted in this site
http://www.debian-administration.org/article/How_to_setup_Postgresql_9.1_Streaming_Replication_Debian_Squeeze

In addition to the steps you posted, I added 2 more steps from the site I provided. The 2 steps are the followings:

- Delete all the files and folders in the standby server before rsync those from the master server.
- In master's postgresql.conf, set the wal_level to hot_standby instead of archive and set the hot_standby to on.

Answer (score 0):

Your standby is continuously recovering which is exactly how streaming replication works in PostgreSQL.  Are you able to log into your standby and run queries?  If so, congrats, it is working.  If not, please post what happens instead.